# Find files on windows created by user

Tags: python, .net, windows, powershell

As part of a document cleanup effort at my company, I've been asked to find a solution for the following problem. We want to give our (very non-techie) user base a way to find their own files on a shared drive. It should be on-demand, meaning the user can use the solution when they see fit and see real-time results.

We have a file [hard disk management tool](http://www.jam-software.com/spaceobserver/?cp=Domain_spaceobserver.com)   in place, so I could write a stored proc against the tool's database and return the data contained there, but there are a couple of drawbacks to this approach:

- not user friendly (again, technology challenged user base)
- data can be up to a week old
- hard to implement an "on-demand" strategy

Ideally, there is a windows utility, like the search bar in windows explorer, where a user could enter their credentials and it would return a list of files they own.

Next best would be a canned tool - any tools come to mind?

Alternately, this is a roll-your-own solution. If it's RYO, what tool would be best? We are a .Net shop, but I prefer python. I don't know any .net and am a beginner in python.  My boss suggested powershell, but I know nothing about that as well.

Another thing to consider: The users have XP Professional desktop but we're moving to Windows 7 sometime in the next few months.

Any suggestions?
TIA.

Comment: I think the first step is to be very clear about what you mean by "their own files". Do you mean files where the ACL has them as the owner?

Comment: Yes, where that person (ID) is the owner (or has modified it, if that data is available).

Comment: Without auditing turned on I don't think that you would ever know about modifications. I'll post a powershell solution based on ACL's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons that you present for not using your existing management tool is difficulty for non technical users. To be clear, that is an issue of presentation, not technology. Here is an example to determine which files a users has ownership of on their own hard drive. You would need to take it and modify it for your specific circumstances. You would also need to determine how to present it in a fashion that meets your user's needs.

```
ls C:\* -rec | %{if($_.GetAccessControl().Owner -like '*USERNAME*'){'{0} - {1}' -f $_.Name, $_.Getaccesscontrol().owner}}
```

Here it is a little more scriptified and less oneliney (I like making up words) along with a quick and dirty display. It will search recursively from whatever search root you give it for files owned by the currently logged on user.

```
$result = @()
$user = '*{0}*' -f $env:USERNAME
$searchRoot = 'G:\'
$files = Get-ChildItem $searchRoot -recurse | Where-Object{$_.GetAccessControl().Owner -like $user}
foreach ($file in $files){
    $temp = New-Object PSCustomObject -Prop @{'Name' = $file.Name;
                                              'Path' = $file.Directory;
                                              'Owner' = $file.GetAccessControl().Owner
    }
    $result += $temp
}
$result | Out-GridView
```

Comment: Thanks. I agree, we can separate data creation from data delivery, but that was issue given my skill-set and knowledge of front-end mechanisms. Do you have a recommendation for a GUI front-end that I could use in conjunction with this powershell code?